# Forcing Ember to wait for value from an Ajax request

Tags: ember.js

I have an Ember application that is typically going to make ajax requests to a server to get its data. The issue I'm facing is that each request needs to have a signature appended to the URL. This signature needs to be calculated often as it is only valid for maybe 10 seconds. The system requires that I request this signature from a server, probably using an ajax request. So, my issue is that Ember can never use the signature returned from the ajax request because it's not designed to wait around, as expected.

The code in question is here: http://jsfiddle.net/veDjq/

In that code, `signature` inside `App.Post` is always `undefined` though I can see that the request for the signature returns a correct value if I `console.log` the `response` in `App.Signature`.

I'm new to Ember so I am more than likely going about this wrong way. In the end, I need to be able to request a new signature each time an Ember object has to request data from the server. I've attempted to use jQuery's `$.ajaxSend` to change the URL, but it doesn't work on GET requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside of your `success` handler, `this` is not what you think it is. It looks like you intend for `this` to be the `App.Signature` class. In order to make that the case, you can set the `context` option of the signature ajax call to `this`.

I would also recommend looking into promises. They will help you clean up this code. For example (untested):

```
App.Signature.reopenClass({
    retrieveSignature: function(){
        return $.ajax({
            url: '/auth/',
        });
    }
});

App.Post.reopenClass({
    postedPosts: [],
    find: function(){
        var postClass = this;
        var signaturePromise = App.Signature.retrieveSignature();
        signaturePromise.done(function(signature){
            var postsRetrieval = $.ajax({
                url: 'http://someserver.com/1/posts/list.json?' + signature,
                dataType: 'json'
            });
            postsRetrieval.done(function(response){
                response.data.forEach(function(post){
                    postClass.postedPosts.addObject(App.Post.create(post))
                });
            });
        });
        return this.postedPosts;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Luke! Looking more closely at the scope of `this` fixed it. I also took your advice and used some promises and it's much nicer. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning `this.signature` while the `$.ajax` request is still running. You might want to pass a callback function containing the main ajax call to `App.Signature.getSignature`, and run that callback from the success or complete callback.

Edit: Hold on. I just realized you had async set to false, so my initial comment is incorrect.